# When to use MaterialToolbar and androidx Toolbar and the difference between both?

Tags: android, material-design, android-toolbar, androidx, material-components-android

When i switched to *AndroidX* i found that the `Toolbar` has moved to `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` also there is a new `MaterialToolbar` introduced as `com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar`
What is the difference between these two and when to use these?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The biggest [difference](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/1.1.0-beta02/lib/java/com/google/android/material/appbar/MaterialToolbar.java#L94) is the use of a [`MaterialShapeDrawable`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/shape/MaterialShapeDrawable) as background implementing some Material features, such as [shaping](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Shape.md) and [elevation overlays](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/theming/Dark.md#elevation-overlays) for Dark Themes.

Answer (score 4):

You can find the answer in the docs of `MaterialToolbar`: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/appbar/MaterialToolbar

Simply MaterialToolbar extends `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` and let it behave as MaterialComponent. The main feature seems to be elevation. You can read through the implementation here:

https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/appbar/MaterialToolbar.java